# How do I get fireballs?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

I was playing a game in G+K when my AI team mates started attacking some city states. I noticed that the catapults and even the pike men were throwing fireballs. How do I do that? I know players can do that.

Comment: That is just part of the animation when a unit tries to take a city... you can't literally get "fireballs"...

Comment: @StrixVaria they are pretty retarded though. They just randomly start attacking CSs. There was a swedish spearman that was in battle for 3000 years because he would never attack the barbarians. My Inca team mates settled on all the tiny islands in the Caribbean (Americas map). They have 23 cities as of 1924. Another ally marched one severely damaged unit straight to the enemy capital city. Alone. The enemy civs always fight for 10 turns, then make peace, wait 30 turns then go to war again.

Comment: @Crubleigh Does it really matter if they are or not?  Does it help your question at all to make note of that fact?

Comment: Pro-tip: If it's removed from your question, don't immediately post it in a comment. It was removed for a reason.

Comment: @fbueckert It's just interesting and I find it funny.

Comment: I didn't know calling something "retarded" was a way to express that it's funny and interesting.

Comment: I found their behavior (being stupid) interesting and funny.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Dom commented, this is the standard animation for many units when attacking cities. You have no control over it, nor does it have any special effect.

Comment: So instead of attacking it, a melee unit will shoot fireballs instead?

Comment: @Crubleigh When attacking a city, that *is* their attack.  Swords and pikes won't do much against walls.

Comment: @Crubleigh It's been a while since I played with the animations turned on, but I think they look more like flaming torches than fireballs. They are certainly *throwing* something--not *shooting*.

Comment: Think of the fireballs as Molotov Cocktails or something.